# How to let the "thank you" page be seen only from users after paypal transaction?

Tags: php, paypal

Hello i have a form on my site and i want that after my user fill the form and make the payment on paypal page he to be redirected to my "thank you" page . but in one condition only users that have

done this procedure would see my thank you page not that a user copy the "thank you" link and send it to someone, the link should not oppend to anyboy outside the users who  have done the payment procedure.

i have archived something like this inside my site but yet with paypal i dont know what to do :
I have this after the validation proces on my proces.php

```
$emotion = $_POST['emotion']; 

if($emotion == 'Basic Pack') { 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['form_finished'] = true; 
header('Location: /buynow/mypage.php'); 

}
```

And this code on the site where the buy now button  from pay pal is placed  "mypage.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['form_finished']) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
?>
```

to let only users that have submitted the form to see that page but with  paypal yet in the middle i dont know how to make it work like i want ,

Any help will be greatly Welcomed.Thanks

Comment: You can use `isset()` on the session variable.

Comment: Are you using PayPal Website Payment Standard?

Comment: yes @Alejandro Arbiza

Comment: @Fred -ii- How do you mean can you please explain me or if you could just write a example, thanks

Comment: Depending on which session variable you wish to use, take this for example `if(isset($_SESSION['session_name']) && !empty($_SESSION['session_name'])){ // do something }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal WPS allows you to setup an auto return page, to which customers are redirected after a payment completed. 
Now, since the auto return consists in a GET request, there isn't any way to prevent users to copy the URL and send it to other people. What you **could** do however, is to set up a mechanism to deprecate the thank you message for every payment transaction. This is not an ideal solution of course, but it is one possibility:

First, go to the payment form you are using in your site to send payment requests to PayPal and add a hidden variable called `return` and set that variable with the URL you want the user to be redirected to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $returnUrl; ?>" />
```

Since you will surely want to have one single return URL per transaction, so you can know if each page was seen or not, the URL could look something like:

```
$returnUrl = "https://www.yoursite.com/thankyou.php?x=123";
```

where `123` is some identification number for "that" particular transaction. To keep track of all pending thanks, you could have a database table, linking the transaction identification with the customer; that way you will be able to display a personalized message.

Now, when PayPal send the customer back to your site, you can check for `$_GET['x']` and build the thank you page:

```
$x = $_GET['x'];
$thankRow = getThankRowFromDatabase( $x );

if ( $thankRow === false )
{
    // redirect to some other page, don't show thank you
}

$customer = getCustomerFromDatabase( $thankRow['customerId'] );

$message = "Thank you {$customer['name']}.";

// Display messages
```

Right after you fetch the "thank you" entry from the database, you can delete the row or mark it as read. This is what will do the trick: if someone tries to see the page again, the corresponding "thank you row" will be marked as already viewed (or maybe deleted), so you just redirect to the home or some other page in your site.

This way, the "thank you" page can be viewed only once; which ultimately makes sense I think.

**EDIT: Additional details.**

The first thing would be to create a data table to keep track of transactions, something simple having two fields:

```
tmp_tx_tracker( orderId, customerId )
```

Since you are surely creating some kind of orders, at the moment you build the payment form, right before sending it to PayPal, you should have an order ID, so you could use that to identify the transaction. The `customerId` field should be trivial.

I assume you already have a table for customers and I assume that said table's primary key is the customer's ID, which I call `customerId'. So, with all this:

```
function getThankRowFromDatabase( $id )
{
    $row = false;

    $qst = "SELECT orderId, customerId FROM tmp_tx_tracker WHERE orderId = '{$id}' ";

    // run the query as you normally do and put the row in $row

    if ( $row !== false )
    {
        // Now we have the information in the variable $row, we can
        // delete the entry from the db so the message won't be available in the future.  
        $qst = "DELETE FROM tmp_tx_tracker WHERE orderId = = '{$id}' ";
        // Execute the query as you usually do.
    }

    return $row;
}
```

Within this situation, I'm not keeping a flag to mark rows as read, instead I'm going to delete the row after reading it.

I suppose you also have some way to fetch customers from your database: that is what you should replace `getCustomerFromDatabase()` with, but to complete the example here:

```
function getCustomerFromDatabase( $id )
{
    $qst = "SELECT name FROM customers WHERE customerId = '{$id}' ";

    // run the query as you normally do and fetch the $row

    return $row;
}
```

Remember that by the moment you build the form to send to PayPal with the payment request, you should have already created the temp row:

```
...
$qst = "INSERT INTO tmp_tx_tracker (orderId, customerId) VALUES ('{$orderId}', '{$customerId}') ";
...
```

As you can see, here I am not using a *read* flag, but I'm deleting the row after reading it so please note the change in the original code that reflects this.

Comment: I'm liking your idea @Alejandro i'm at testing it right now , thanks

Comment: I'm getting a error on this part of code " $thankRow = getThankRowFromDatabase( $x );" ?

Comment: Oh, you should take that as pseudo-code, those functions don't really exist; they are just a way to describe the general process. `getThankRowFromDatabase()` is a theoretical function that is supposed to return a row. I don't know how you access the database, so I tried to use a very descriptive name so the purpose comes clear from it. The implementation of the details depend on your environment. If you provided more info that showed how you access your database, I could offer some more "realistic" code in the answer.

Comment: sorry i'm a noob in php, i acces my database with this code : $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); you know the values are all wroten one time and i use simply this to call them when i need to

Comment: Ok, be aware that `mysql_x` functions are discouraged due to security issues and even deprecated since PHP 5.5. Please google `MySQLi` and take some time to learn about it before going any further with this application.

Comment: This is what i call  a great explanation @Aljeandro yes i will look forward to learn about MySQLi for sure ,i'm at testing besides this thank you

Comment: i now i will have a hard time figuring all this out but i will do my best